# Postgres : Out of memory error while importing a .sql file

Tags: postgresql

I have taken a dump of postgres database from server, let's say abc.sql whose total size is 56 GB. I created a local database in postgres, let's say import_here where I have to import the abc.sql.
I am using the following command to import:

```
sudo -u postgres psql import_here < abc.sql
```

I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried the solutions from the following link but nothing worked for me:

[https://italux.medium.com/postgresql-out-of-memory-3fc1105446d#:~:text=The%20most%20common%20cause%20of,writing%20to%20temporary%20disk%20files](https://italux.medium.com/postgresql-out-of-memory-3fc1105446d#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20cause%20of,writing%20to%20temporary%20disk%20files)

I am using ubuntu 20.04.
I am also sharing disk space status for your reference:
[image]

Comment: The error messages suggest that the dump is not interpreted correctly. Find the **first** error message and add it to the question. Never mind the OOM error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks. I was unable to see the first error message because it was crossing quickly so I recorded the video and saw it. The main error was that the postgis scripts were missing. **sudo apt-get install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-scripts** fixed the problem for me.